# Optimistic Backbone application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, optimistic

I just wanted to know if there are any articles, discussions and general advice on building an optimistic application?

As of 0.9 Backbone changed its models to be optimistic by default. Now if I am saving/updating a model, do I need to wait for a response from the server? Obviously if not, the results are immediate which leads to a much snappier application. This can also lead to problems if there is an error when updating or creating a new model on the server. Which leads me to my next point.

If I am building an optimistic application, how do I handle errors? Would it be feasible to presume the model has been created/updated and if not store the data in localstorage and periodically try save to the server? I have not looked extensively at [this plugin](https://github.com/Ask11/backbone.offline), but I think it has the same mentality.

What are your opinions and suggestions? Lets presume I am building a non-transactional application.